# Simplify two brackets with fractional powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify, $(b^{1/2} - 4b^{-1/2})(b^{1/2} + 4b^{-1/2})
$

Is answer $-15b$?

Comment: $(b^{1/2} - 4b^{-1/2})(b^{1/2} + 4b^{-1/2}) = \dfrac{(b-4)(b+4)}{b}$

Answer (score 1):

it can be simplified after the binomial formula $$(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$$ after this formula we get $$b-16b^{-1}$$

Comment: Thanks! I went through again and got this to be my answer too. Unsure where I went wrong the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Put $a=b^{\frac{1}{2}}$ then the expression becomes

$$(a-\frac{4}{a})(a+\frac{4}{a})$$

$$=a^2-\frac{16}{a^2}$$

$$=b-\frac{16}{b}.$$